# Error: No view found for id androidx(Jetpack) Preference library

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-jetpack

I was following the instructions [on docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/) to use Android Jetpack preference library, but I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ ... activity.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090111 (... :id/settings_container) for fragment SettingsFragment
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090111 (... :id/settings_container) for fragment SettingsFragment
```

as I think this usually happens when there is no container to mount the fragment, but in my case there is a container(`settings_container`).

My code looks like below

**SettingsActivity**

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

**SettingsFragment**

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main, rootKey)
}
```

**activity_settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/settings_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.SettingsActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

**pref_main.xml** (shortened)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <PreferenceCategory
            app:key="data_sync_category"
            app:title="@string/pref_data_sync_category">

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat app:key="data_sync_status"
                                app:title="@string/pref_data_sync_status_title"
                                app:summary="@string/pref_data_sync_status_summary"
                                android:defaultValue="true"
        />
        <ListPreference app:key="what_data_sync"
                        app:title="@string/pref_sync_frequency_title"
                        app:summary="@string/pref_sync_frequency_summary"
                        android:entries="@array/pref_sync_frequency_titles"
                        android:entryValues="@array/pref_sync_frequency_values"
                        android:defaultValue="30"
                        android:negativeButtonText="@null"
                        android:positiveButtonText="@null"
        />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

As you can see code is almost identical to the code in documentation.
I tried invalidate and restart, did not work.

Please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there isn't a container.

You never use `setContentView()` in your Activity, so that layout doesn't exist. `tools:context` is an IDE-only feature.

You need to use

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
```

right after calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.

Comment: thanks it works now. As you can see in the docs there is no setContentView, so example is incomplete.

Comment: may be they remove trivial parts from the code snippets, in order to simplify things.

Comment: It's not trivial as it looks then :)

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ ... activity.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090111 (... :id/settings_container) for fragment SettingsFragment
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090111 (... :id/settings_container) for fragment SettingsFragment
```

according your code you did't set layout for activity

you are giving reference of `settings_container` but its not found in activity layout because they dont have layout file so you need to `setContentView` for your activity

---

**`setContentView(R.layout.name)`**

```
public void setContentView (int layoutResID)
```

Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

---

Replace your activity kt file with

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```